# How to identify non linear components of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

What mathematical technique could help me identify  the non-linear components of the following vectors?

```
1)[0, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12, 14, 19, 20, 21]
```

Expected output for (1)`=7`

```
2)[5, 6, 7, 1, 9, 12, 15, 16, 17, 13, 14, 18, 19]
```

Expected output  for (2)`=1,13,14`

The expected output shows where the deviation from linearity occurs.

Both z-score for outlier detection and standard deviation are not suitable.

Rate of change (slope) might do, but I don't know how to make it work.

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: why is $ [0, 2,  4, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12, 14, 19, 20, 21]$ linear? Do you mean non-decreasing?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh, my understanding is that if it increases or decreases progressively, it is leaner. so in example `1` above, if you remove `7`, it becomes linear, my question is how do I identify  `7` that alters the linear flow.

Comment: is $[0, 1, 50, 63]$ "linear" to you?

Comment: In my case, I'll say yes, although the rate of change is not uniform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a name to such problem if we want the subsequence to be increasing, it is known as [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence). It can be solved in complexity $O(n\log(n))$ and an algorithm using binary search and array is provided in the link.

For your problem, since you consider both increasing and decreasing, you can first solved the problem to find the longest increasing subsequence and also reverse your array to solve for the longest decreasing subsequence.

Comment: many thanks for your solution, its just what I needed. Perfect!